# Can I configure Matlab's Unit Test Framework to fail for specific warnings?

Tags: matlab

I have a Matlab model and lots of unit tests, based on Matlab's own class-based unit test framework (matlab.unittest.TestCase and matlab.unittest.TestRunner). Tests produce quite a lot of warnings, some of which are serious from my pov. I would like the framework to report a test case failure if some of the specific warnings pop up.

A test runner can be easily configured to fail on warnings. But then it will fail on any warning:

```
import matlab.unittest.TestRunner;
import matlab.unittest.plugins.FailOnWarningsPlugin;
runner = TestRunner.withNoPlugins;
runner.addPlugin(FailOnWarningsPlugin);
```

A test runner can be also configured to ignore specific warnings, for example:

```
runner.addPlugin(FailOnWarningsPlugin('Ignoring',{'MATLAB:singularMatrix'}));
```

Here is the documentation:

https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.plugins.failonwarningsplugin-class.html

Using 'Ignoring' flag and listing lots of warnings seems troublesome.
Is there a way to do it the other way around? That is, to force my test cases to fail only on certain warnings and ignore others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can temporarily set warning to be reported as errors:

```
s= warning('error', 'MATLAB:DELETE:FileNotFound'); % set warning as an error
warn(s) % restore the warning to non-error
```

Reference: https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/trapping-warnings-efficiently

Comment: And if you want to use this carefully within the unit testing framework, you could create your own Fixture that would store the previous state of the warning message, set it to error, and then reset it to the previous when the test was torn down.

Comment: Thanks @Anthony. Turning specific warnings into errors was actually what first came to my mind but I wasn't aware how easily it can be done. I wonder why that useful trick is not mentioned in the Matlab reference page for 'warning'.